# How to use friend function in multiple classes

Tags: c++, function, friend

I am trying to create a non-member `operator<<`. However, I want the operator to be accessible to two of my classes. The operator is

```
void operator<< (ClassA & a, ClassB & b)
```

In the two classes public part, I say:

```
friend void operator<< (ClassA & a, ClassB & b);
```

However, it turned out that the operator can access the private member variable in `CLass B` but cannot access private member variable in `Class A`.

Why?

The real code:
In the cpp file:

```
void operator<< (Hand& h, Deck& d){

    h.hand.push_back(d.card[0]);
    sort(h.hand.begin(),h.hand.end());
    d.card.erase(d.card.begin());
}
```

In the header file:

```
class Deck {

private:
    vector<Card> card;

public:
    friend void operator<< (Hand& , Deck& );
};

class Hand {

private:
    vector<Card> hand;

public:
    friend void operator<< (Hand& , Deck& );
};
```

And the card file didn't work.

Comment: As long as you put a friend declaration in both classes, it should be fine. Probably there's something wrong with those declarations, or with the definition of your operator. You should show the real code

Comment: Are you sure you want << to return void? You won't be able to chain or use the return value and will certainly introduce "gotchas" in your code.

Comment: @milleniumbug "certainly"? That's nonsense. This is not a stream insertion operator. You can still implement a stream insertion overload of the operator no problem, causing no particular problem. That said, I'd probably prefer this to be a non-operator function.

Comment: @user1933 "The card file did not work" - did you include the header file? What was the problem? Was there an error message? What was it?

Comment: @sehe Until someone uses it as an subexpression, and gotchas are about meaning of `a << b`. That said, my remark seems to be outdated, now that OP posted the whole code.

Comment: @milleniumbug: It can be used in a subexpression in the ternary operator and the comma operator. For your amusement: [`return 0 ? throw 1 : hand<<deck, 42;` is perfectly valid C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7012f0d6ee532fcffe2d0c05765c4f05-ecc2db3aae4a4a26bf7b459ca30e0a7f). The fact that `hand<<deck` becomes invalid in non-void context is not a problem at all. If you ***didn't*** define `operator<<` at all, it wouldn't suddenly become more meaningful in those contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** to the edited question: the following code compiles no problem for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
typedef int Card;

class Hand; // NOTE forward declaration

class Deck {
private:
    std::vector<Card> card;

public:
    friend void operator<< (Hand& , Deck&);
};

class Hand {
private:
    std::vector<Card> hand;

public:
    friend void operator<< (Hand& , Deck&);
};

void operator<< (Hand& h, Deck& d) {
    h.hand.push_back(d.card[0]);
    std::sort(h.hand.begin(),h.hand.end());
    d.card.erase(d.card.begin());
}

int main()
{
}
```

**Did you forget to forward declare Hand in the header file**?

---

You might be confused because you *can* define the body of the static friend function *inside* one of the class's declarations.

Still, a friend *declaration* is always just a *declaration*. So, in fact

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct A
{
    friend bool operator<<(A const&, B const&);
};

struct B
{
    friend bool operator<<(A const&, B const&);
};

bool operator<<(A const&, B const&)
{
    // access to both A and B
    return false;
}
```

Is equivalent, to

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct A
{
    friend bool operator<<(A const&, B const&)
    {
        // access to both A and B
        return false;
    }
};

struct B
{
    friend bool operator<<(A const&, B const&);
};
```

Comment: Hmm, how is it related to the question?

Comment: @Slava note that the question was edited, I answered when it said http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15232809/2 . I have also just updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I see thanks, I thought about forward declaration as well, but would that friend function declaration compile without forward declaration of the class?

Comment: @sehe Yep, I didn't declare the class at the beginning. Our teacher has never taught us of that. Thanks!